# Roslyn: Get formatted method signature/declaration

Tags: c#, roslyn, text-formatting, method-signature

I have `MethodDeclarationSyntax` or `IMethodSymbol`, but I could not find any way, how to access formatted method name:

```
namespace XXX.YYY.ZZZ
{    
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But all I can access are texts formatted like this:

```
public System.Void XXX.YYY.ZZZ.MyClass.MyMethod()
```

I saw some examples with `Formatter.Format`. But they all need document/workspace etc and I am not interested to get adjustable formatting based on solution or VS Setting, but simple common C# general formatting for method signature:

```
public void MyMethod()
```

Very much same with parameters in other cases:

```
public System.Void XXX.YYY.ZZZ.MyClass.MyMethod(System.Sting myString, System.Int 
 index)
```

Is there some way to do that in Roslyn?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the formatting you are expecting?  I'm not sure what you mean by "same with parameters".  Do you mean `System.String` vs. `string`?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, but I have found the trick:). Roslyn is nicely misleading a little:). Data that are shown as objects ToString() representation are different in visual studio debug view and with actual call. For example a type was showing, that it is System.String or System.Void, but calling ToString explicitly prodived string, void. It is pretty much confusing, even when I understand the need to present namespace, types can be tracked easily when there are similar or same names in different namespaces, but still, it can make a person to spin on the dime for long time, cursing and such:)

Comment: Feel free to provide this as a self-answer.  Just make sure it's exhaustive enough that it will help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the trick is the difference between what the Roslyn object show in debugging mode and what they actually provide with ToString() methods.

Sometimes namespace is part of the output for Identifier names, but mostly not, yet object representation can mislead in debugging mode.

The best way is to obtain the string by ToString or other means in first place, even when a variable, field or constant is showing in debug mode something else:).